# Storing the hex value FF in an unsigned 8 bit integer produces garbage instead of -1

Tags: c++, numbers, integer, hex

Behold my code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  uint8_t no_value = 0xFF;
  std::cout << "novalue: " << no_value << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Why does this output: novalue: ▒

On my terminal it looks like:

[image]

I was expecting -1.

After all, if we:

[image]

we get:

[image]

Comment: Why do you expect -1 for an *unsigned* int? if it wasn't taken for a char, the expected result should be 255.

Comment: #@FelixPalmen you are right.

Comment: `std::cout` is a syntax error in C . Use printf() instead (and choose either %c or %d or %u to display the value)

Comment: Why is this tagged as 'c' when all the code is c++?  Suggest modifying the tag

Comment: @user3629249 You love freaking out, don't you? Question is fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`uint8_t` is most likeley `typedef`-ed to `unsigned char`.  When you pass this to the `<<` operator, the overload for `char` is selected, which causes your `0xFF` value to be interpreted as an ASCII character code, and displaying the "garbage".

If you really want to see -1, you should try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
  uint8_t no_value = 0xFF;
  std::cout << "novalue (cast): " << (int)(int8_t)no_value << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Note that I first cast to `int8_t`, which causes your previously unsigned value to be instead interpretted as a signed value. This is where 255 becomes -1.  Then, I cast to `int`, so that `<<` understands it to mean "integer" instead of "character".

Your confusion comes from that fact that Windows calculator doesn't give you options for signed / unsigned -- it always considers values signed. So when you used an `uint8_t`, you made it unsigned.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  uint8_t no_value = 0x41;
  std::cout << "novalue: " << no_value << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

You will get this output:

> novalue: A

`uint8_t` probably the same thing as `unsigned char`.
`std::cout` with chars will output the char itself and not the char's ASCII value.